# How to build html newsletter responsive block order

Tags: html, css, email, newsletter

I want to build 2 columns block which having 3 element inside, element 1 and element 2 are on the left while element 3 is on the right. The problem is I want it on the mobile version, the order is 1,3,2 (now it shows 1,2,3). How can I build it? [description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl6HE.png)

```
<style>
@media all and (max-width: 600px){
 .on600-widthfull { width:100%;min-width:100%; }
}
</style>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th class="on600-widthfull">
   <table class="on600-widthfull">
    <tr><th>1</th></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th></tr>
   </table>
  </th>
  <th class="on600-widthfull">3</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use `bootstrap` for that, for more information follow this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/

Comment: @NishargShah You cannot use Bootstrap for email.

Comment: why i cant use bootstrap for making front-end look

Comment: @NishargShah The most obvious reason is that JavaScript will never work in email. Email development is NOT web development.

Comment: what a joke !! i know both have different but for validation you want to use ajax or simple JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple example of how this would work.

First off, you need a @media query in the style sheet:

```
<style>
td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .stack-in-mobile {
      display: block !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Next, you need a table. Your 1-3-2 idea will never work. This will:

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td class="stack-in-mobile">1</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="stack-in-mobile">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stack-in-mobile">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It works in every major email client, but it has no formatting, so you'll need to work on that. The basic idea is to have a class in mobile that re-formats the table.

I would suggest looking at some existing email templates to get a better idea how they work and follow that example. I suggest one like Cerberus.

- https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/

Good luck.

```css
td {
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.stack-in-mobile {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
  }
```

```html
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
<td class="stack-in-mobile">1</td>
<td rowspan="2" class="stack-in-mobile">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="stack-in-mobile">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi gwally, thank you for your answer, that rowspan idea is good, it is working!

Comment: @leafyaa There's nothing like ancient table techniques to get the job done. They're all integrated into email.